# Can you launch a Spring boot rest application on multiple threads?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, soapui

I have a Rest application built with spring boot. I want to launch multiple instances of  that application to different threads in order to reduce the time needed to run the integration test.

Has anybody tried this before, if yes how did you do it and what did you use?
If it is not possible could you please explain why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you "launching" it? If it's external (connecting over a local socket), then it's just an ordinary server and multithreaded already. If not, you'll probably want multiple contexts and will need to configure your runner to partition by test class.

Comment: Your application is already multithreaded. It's running within an embedded Tomcat instance, which is a mature, high performance application server. Ofcourse you can start multiple instances of the application, too. Just use a different port, by specifying `--server.port=xxxx` command line argument when running your JAR. I don't think it will make your tests go faster though.

Comment: Do you guys know a tutorial on how to do this, or any suggestion on where to start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said already, it is multithreaded already and it is not about having multiple instances or threads to increase the speed of your integration tests, it is about tests themselves.

As an example, if your REST application using SQL database, make sure that your tests are using H2 database and etc, etc.

Also, check how often your Spring Context is start/stoping.